# Multiple isset checks php

Tags: php, isset

I'm trying to implement multiple `if(isset())` statements but I can't get it to work.

example:

```
if (isset($_GET['a']) or isset($_GET['b'])) {
    // HTML
} else {
    // HTML
    <a href="?link=a>LinkA</a>
    <a href="?link=b>LinkB</a>
}
```

When I click a or b I still got the else statement executed.

I also tried:

```
if (isset($_GET['a'] or $_GET['b']))
```

but then I get a error

I'm trying to display different pages on different $_GET requests.
Can someone point me in the right direction or is this not the right way to do this?

Comment: If `<a href="?link=a>LinkA</a>` etc. is what you're actually using, you need to echo that, not just inject pure HTML into PHP. Plus `$_GET['a']` that should be `$_GET['link']` since you're using `?link` as a reference, then check if the value is "a" or "b".

Answer (score 1):

Change `if (isset($_GET['a']) or isset($_GET['b']))` To:

```
if ( (isset($_GET['link']) && $_GET['link'] == 'a') OR (isset($_GET['link']) && $_GET['link'] == 'b']) )
```

Answer (score 0):

You are checking wrong variable.

You need to check `$_GET ['link']`